# Reset auto increment without using ALTER TABLE statement mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to reset the AUTO_INCREMENT field for one of the usecase in my application. I know how to do that using ALTER TABLE statement as given below:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

I wanted to know if it is possible to reset the AUTO_INCREMENT without using ALTER TABLE statement. The reason I want to do that is because ALTER TABLE statement auto commits the current transaction. The reason I want to do that is because I am executing a sequence of mysql queries, where I have turned off auto commit and committing only when all queries are executed successfully. Here, one of the query being executed is resetting auto increment. However, ALTER TABLE statement seems to auto commit the current transaction, thereby, losing the atomicity in case of any exception occurs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't think of any scenario where you should regularly change the autoincrement for a table if your database is correctly designed. Btw, you cannot reset the auto increment without ddl commands - all of which would fommit the current transaction.

Comment: Actually, the scenario is I am deleting all entries of a table and updating it with new ones. So, if the table had 4 entries before, the new entries will have id starting from 5.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete all entries and reset the auto increment, then use [truncate table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/truncate-table.html) statement:

> Any AUTO_INCREMENT value is reset to its start value. This is true
>   even for MyISAM and InnoDB, which normally do not reuse sequence
>   values.

Comment: Well, `truncate table` statement also auto commits the current transaction. And auto committing the current transaction is something we are trying to avoid.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your requirements contradict each other. You are asking for the impossible.

Comment: I know..that's the reason I posted it here to find out if there is any other way :)

Comment: To reset the auto increment, you need a ddl statement